# Spring Security:custom query

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have question:

It is possible to customize query at `authentication provider` using `jdbc-user-service` ?

For example:
i have an application where users chose there roles when they insert there logins and passwords, so i want to create a query like this:

```
select login,password, enabled from xxxx where username=?
```

and after this query i want `to attribute to this person (returned by this query),if exists, a role which is xxxx. I should also pass the role selected to this query`.

```
xxxx is the role which is selected by user at first
```

I hope that you understand me and sorry if it is a stupid question , i'm still beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider writing custom authentication service class, instead of `jdbc-user-service` query. You hold the user role somehow and while building `authorities` of logged in user in `UserDetails` service, add appropriate role in the collection. OR The role of logged in user can be manipulated later. You are gonna have to try and manipulate spring security context. Read this [forum page](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/101786-spring-security-how-to-add-remove-authorities-of-the-user-after-he-logs-in) to know more.